# Accessing Tweets of specific time Interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, streaming, tweets

As of now, I can able to access tweets of a particular count from specific channel(like 100,500)--Etc
How to access Tweets from specific time to other specific time of a particular channel
Eg: I have to access Tweets from (2nd March 2018 12:00 Am to 3rd March 2018 2:00 pm)

I have found one way from Github to access tweets, But I am getting errors, Can anybody help me in solving the Error.
[Picture Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTuo0.png)

Thank you.

Comment: no tweets will be found for a date older than one week. and you can check for the tweets time if it will falls between your time interval (Note: must not be older than a week) then you can save it otherwise discard it.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the Twitter Search API:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets

You won't be able though to access tweets older than one week and to request all the data available, for that you'll need to pay and gain access to Twitter premium API

You can find more useful information here : https://developer.twitter.com/en.html